# Java TCP communication transmission data structures

Tags: java, tcp, custom-component

I am trying to make a small multiplayer game in Java. I got the tpc connection working, but for now i can only transmit strings. I would like to transmit more sophisticated data in packets, which would contain all the necessary data for synchronizing the game. Is it possible to transmit some kind of custom structures, or data from class instances in one tcp package? Or what would be a good way to do it(i googled but i couldn't find something that would fit my needs)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the keyword to look for here is [*serialization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). That is the process of converting a data structure to a chunk of bytes that can be sent across a socket or other transmission medium.

One way to do this is to use the [Google Protocol Buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) library, which has bindings for use with Java.

Comment: It works, but i had to merge the client and server project into a single project, and include the classes each other classes. When i had them as separate projects it would throw exceptions when receiving the instance, no matter that the two classes were identical in both projects. Any way to get it working with 2 different projects?

Comment: I don't know of a specific reason why it wouldn't work with two different projects (assuming all else is the same), but without knowing exactly what you did it's hard to say. However, maintaining two copies of the protocol definition in different projects will be prone to error (getting them out of sync), so it's probably best to combine them. You could probably have the protocol definition in a third project that is included in the first two.

Comment: Hazard: 
I had this bug, where all instances were identical, and the game seemed frozen. That is due to caching, and the reset method must be used in such cases. Example that i found: objOut.reset();

Answer (score 1):

The most basic, yet not optimal way is to use the [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)-marker interface, see for example here: [Discover the secrets of the Java Serialization API](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/).

The better way is to use some [binary protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_protocol), see here for some examples: [general-purpose binary protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352433/general-purpose-binary-protocols) or cook your own.

Answer (score 0):

**-** If you are not satisfied with the plain String going across the socket, you can then Use `Serialization`.

**-** `Serialization` must be used when the same java program is used to write and read the data.

**-** `Serialization` **flattens and inflates the Object** while storing and retrieving respectively.

**-** Its actually **not** the Object, but its `Instance variables` are used saved and later used to resurrect an identical object on the heap....

Answer (score 0):

`I would like to transmit more sophisticated data in packets, which would contain all the necessary data for synchronizing the game.`

If these data are `Serializable` (for example, your data consists of only primitives, string and array of primitives or array of strings), then you can use some standard `Collection` like `Vector`, `List`, `Map` etc to hold your data. They are serializable (check their documentation). So what you need to just use this:

```
objectOutputStream.writeObject(data)
```

Assuming that you are using `ObjectOutputStream` to send packets. But if you don't need to create your own custom data structure, you need to tag it with `java.io.Serializable`, as others have pointed out.

**NOTE:** In a class that implements  Serializable, you must ensure that every
instance variable of that class is a Serializable type.